# Javascript: пропажа внешней переменной в функции после вызова другой функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Вызываю одну функцию из другой и пропадает внешняя переменная

```
function addFakes(){
    var arr=[];
    for (i=1;i<=60;i++){
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}

function addPlayers(){
    for(i=1;i<=players;i++){
        player[i]={};
        var deck = addFakes(); // без вызова этой функции все работает
        // Здесь появляется ошибка pen.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'deck' of undefined
        player[i].deck = deck;
        player[i].hand=[];


    }
}
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо написать for *(var i=1;i<=60;i++)* и *for(var i=1;i<=players;i++)*, чтобы скрипт нормально работал. Ты забыл "*var*". Счетчики всегда объявляются ВНУТРИ локального кода функции, чтобы после ее отработки быть удаленными вместе с контекстом-объектом Local отработавшей функции, потому что объект-контекст Local отработавшей функции уже никому не нужен после ее отработки (только память засоряет), важен лишь результат работы функции.

Comment: большое спасибо, я этого не знал :)

Comment: пожалуйста). сегодня я тебе подсказал, а завтра, может быть, ты и мне подскажешь в чем-то, что знаешь лучше. так этот сайт и работает. есть еще англоязычный стаковерфлоу. там больше людей сидит, и вероятность получить хороший ответ еще выше, чем на русскоязычном.

Answer (score 1):

Объявите переменную "i" в обоих функциях след. образом:

**let i = *значение;***

это новый **более правильный способ, предоставляемый новым стандартом ES-2015** для объявления локальных переменных вместо var.
Детальнее: https://learn.javascript.ru/let-const

На данный момент во вложенной функции вы объявили переменную "i" как глобальную. Ее нужно объявить как локальную.

Comment: Не нужен тут ни какой `let`, тут функции у автора и `var` тут отлично будет работать! И во всех браузерах!

Comment: @Visman , 1 - я просто хотел дополнить ответ Dimon . 2 - можно пользоваться WebPack и использовать все удобства предоставляемые новым стандартом и при этом все везде будет работать. 3 - пусть автор сам решает

Comment: спасибо, но думаю, буду пока с var, чтобы лишнего не подключать

Answer (score 0):

Я понял в чем дело. Дело в переменной i, которая есть в обеих функциях

Comment: i - локальная переменная!!!

Comment: @CraftPE, в представленном коде - нет, тут она глобальная.