# Почему меняется значение из вызывающего кода в вызываемом?

Tags: javascript

Имею следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   ...
    function funcA(items) {
        // Ранее этого места index нигде не фигурирует.
        for (index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            var a = funcB(items[index]);
            ...
        }
    }
}
function funcB(id) {
    for (index = 0; index < initJson.length; index++) {
        item = initJson[index];
        if (item.id == id) {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

В функции `funcA` и функции `funcB` я использую переменные в цикле с одним и тем же именем (`index`), которые на первый взгляд вообще никак не связаны между собой, так как должны существовать в разны «пространствах видимости». Используя отладчик я вижу, что значение переменной `index` в функции `funcA`, после вызова `funcB` становится равным последнему значению в функции `funcB`.  Подскажите, почему я наблюдаю подобное поведение? Поведение не возникает, если в цикле я объявляю переменную как `var index = 0`, все же, не понятно, каким образом и почему переменная из области видимости вызывающего кода попадает и изменятся в вызываемом.

Comment: потому что конструкция index = 0 без var создает глобальную переменную

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму  Абсолютно всегда и даже внутри функции?

Comment: не "абсолютно всегда", в strict mode не создает, а просто ругается на такое. Ну и разумеется если index раньше объявлена (где-то в теле функции сделан var index;) то не создает

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Буду крайне вам признателен за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Мне признаться сейчас лень, нюансом создания переменных посвящен целый раздел спецификации (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations), да и точно где-нибудь Grundy на это отвечал, надо подождать пока он появится). Я бы кроме того рекомендовал использовать для индексов циклов let по возможности, это избавит от потенциальных проблем с пониманием замыканй)

Comment: В общем да, попытка обращения к переменной без var (let/const) - вызовет создание такой глобальной переменной если выше в цепочке скоупов до глобального нет переменной с таким же именем

Comment: [похожий вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559990/186999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Область видимости создают функции и модули (как IIFE через тэг `script` (загруженный ли код или который внутри)) и ES6 модули.
Относительно новый стандарт услышал слёзы разрабов и ввёл блочную видимость (`{}`) через `let`, `const`.

Объявление через `var` пишут переменную в ближайшую внешнюю область.
Объявления без `var` пишут в `window` (неизвестно чем руководствовались создатели, но, видимо, забористая дурь была). Это явление вырезается ошибкой в строгом режиме.

`let` и т. п. ограничиваются ближайшим внешним блоком.

Зная это, можно понять что в Вашем коде используется **одна и та же** переменная.
Допиши любой доступный модификатор видимости и всё заработало бы:

```js
function a(){
  // Без указания видимости, в window
  b = 41;
}
a();
console.info(b, window.b === b); // 41, true

function a(){
  // В видимость функции
  var b = 42;
}
a();
console.info(b); // ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

Блочная видимость:

```js
function a(){
  let b = 42;
  {
    let b = 41;
  }
  console.info(b); // 42
}
a();
```

Comment: вообще говоря модули и _отдельный тег script_ - это не одно и то же

Comment: Так я и написал (в скобках просто подробнее о определении (что именно не про `import/export`)).

Comment: тогда причем тут модули? теги скрипт не создают _отдельную_ область видимости :)

Comment: Хм, вроде создают. Из одного не прокинешь видимость в другой тэг.

Comment: Таки ты попробуй :-)

Comment: Странно, вроде раньше работало.

Comment: _модули (как IIFE через тэг script (загруженный ли код или который внутри))_ - вот вообще непонятно что ты тут имеешь ввиду

Comment: Самовызов (изолировать область видимости) + подключение (через `script` = модуль.

Comment: `F` в IIFE это как раз функция, про которую ты говорил уже, а про скрипт, определились, что он не модуль

Comment: Хватит придираться :) Функция изолирует, `script` подключает.

Comment: ну так суть в том, что если script уберешь. у тебя ничего не поменяется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57126/discussion-between-other-and-grundy).

Answer (score 4):

Как уже было сказано без var создается глобальная переменная. Так уж устроено, потому,если объявляете переменную внутри функции и хотите,чтоб она была видна только в функции, то делайте это через var, тогда её область видимости будет ограничена этой функцией.

[Здесь неплохо описана область видимости](https://learn.javascript.ru/global-object)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы вы добавить в ваш ответ минимальный пример, который бы наглядно показывал что к чему.

Comment: Я бы с радостью, но это уже позже, так как не за компьютером. По ссылке , которую я добавил есть примеры и задачи. Вообще советую пройти этот учебник - это очень хорошая альтернатива книгам, но без книг никуда.